# How to fix SQL Agent Job using Windows Security after password change

Tags: sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent

I have some sql agent jobs that are using Windows NT Integrated Security to run (as specified in the Maintenance Plan's Manage Connections window)...eg. Translog backups.

While logged in as this account, I changed its password. Now the maintenance job is failing.

`reason: Error authenticating proxy DOMAIN\Account, system error: The user name or password is incorrect`

How do you fix this?

What I've tried:

- Logging out of the server and back on
- Per [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1973/changing-passwords-for-logins-used-with-sql-server-maintenance-plans/), Changed the connection to use SQL Authentication and then restarted SQL Agent...it still fails, but the error still is the same showing the same DOMAIN/Account that failed, so it is still using the Windows authentication instead of the new SQL login provided.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

The job step is also using a Proxy account, which is the same account. So you need to change the proxy account credentials as well.

Comment: You should accept this as the answer.  Answering your own questions is encouraged.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I will, but can't until 2 days have passed per stackexchange rules.